# C# Selenium wedriver: Is it possible to make click on object that level above

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

I have many objects in one page which xpath is:

//td[@class='bxec-day' or @class='bxec-day bxec-holiday' and not(@class='bxec-day bxec-day-past-hol')]//div//div//a[text()='10']

they differ only by text in the last "a":
a[text()='5']
a[text()='6']
etc.

i don't need to click on "a" but i neet to make click on next to the last or last div.

construction like this //td[@class='bxec-day' or @class='bxec-day bxec-holiday' and not(@class='bxec-day bxec-day-past-hol') and @text()='10'] doesn't work.

Is it possible to go one or two level up in xpath? Or maybe there is some other solutions?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the actual html it would be a whole lot less confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. is probably what you need. So in your example:

//td[@class='bxec-day' or @class='bxec-day bxec-holiday' and not(@class='bxec-day bxec-day-past-hol')]//div//div//a[text()='10']/../../

This however goes up in a tree so if there are any other elements between 'div' and 'a' you need to take it into consideration.